# Problem inverting a function

Tags: functions, inverse

I have this function:

$$v(t)=\sqrt{\frac F c} \tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{Fc}}{m} t \right)$$

I can visually see that t=6.3 when v=27.8, so why don't I get t=6.3 upon putting v=27.8 in this supposedly inverse function?!?

$$t(v)=\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{Fc}}\tanh^{-1}\left(v\sqrt{\frac c F}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

We invert the function as we would any other function:

$$v=\sqrt{\frac{F}{c}}\tanh\left(\frac{\sqrt{Fc}}{m}t\right)$$

Dividing both sides by $\sqrt{\frac{F}{c}}$, we get:

$$\sqrt{\frac{c}{F}}\,v=\tanh\left(\frac{\sqrt{Fc}}{m}t\right)$$

Taking the inverse hyperbolic tangent of both sides:

$$\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{F}}\,v\right)=\frac{\sqrt{Fc}}{m}t$$

We then divide both sides by $\frac{\sqrt{Fc}}{m}$, to give:

$$t=\frac{m}{\sqrt{Fc}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{F}}\,v\right)$$

So your expression for $t(v)$ is correct, so it must be merely a numerical issue you are having.

Comment: I know, I replaced "t" by "t expression" in v(t) expression and I (obviously) got v, but I can't figure out my numerical error.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with information regarding $m$, $F$ and $c$ so we might be better able to assist then?

Comment: Is there any online CAS which supports assigning vlaues to variable before calculating expression value, to check my mah?

Comment: If you just use the values in the expression then you can use Wolfram|Alpha, but I'm not sure about preassigning values to variables in that. It doesn't seem unfeasible though, perhaps look through the documentation?

Comment: I can provide you all information you WANT on F, C and M, but I don't think you NEED them, they will just add unneeded complexity to the problem. These are the formulas for electric vehicle speed depending on air drag and for 0-to-60mph-time ; F = traction force = $\frac {T_e G}r$ , $T_e$ = engine torque, G=overall gear ratio (=~8 for electric vehicles), r = wheel diameter (=~0.31 m) . "c" takes into account air drag, being $c=\frac 1 2 \rho C_d A$, $C_d$=drag coefficient =~0.30 , A=frontal area =~2.2 m^2 , m= vehicle mass.

Comment: reference: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106352/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-electric-car-to-go-from-0-to-60-mph?noredirect=1#comment221297_106352

Comment: Anyway, just for testing, which values for v and t do you get using these input data? F=6200 N , c = 0.40 and m = 1400 kg ?

Comment: I get for $F=6200$, $c=0.4$, $m=1400$, $t=6.3$; $v\approx 27.4421$. If I then put that value for $v$ into the inverse expression, I get $6.3$ exactly as the result. I used the following mathematica code: `In[7]:= ClearAll[F, c, m, t]

In[8]:= F = 6200; c = 0.40; m = 1400; t = 6.3;

In[9]:= v = Sqrt[F/c] Tanh[Sqrt[F c]/m t]

Out[9]= 27.4421

In[10]:= τ = m/Sqrt[F c] ArcTanh[Sqrt[c/F] v]

Out[10]= 6.3`

Comment: I wonder if it is a Winplot issue, as I'm using it to plot both functions. Which other SW can I use on windows (or online) to plot a function like these and see the calculated values?

Comment: Damn!! Winplot has no definition for atanh!!! Hence plotting atanh(x) results in plotting a*tanh(x) with obviously wrong results!! By defining a new function $ath(x)=\frac 1 2 ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ I eventually got right results.

Answer (score 0):

Winplot has no definition for atanh()

Hence plotting atanh(x) results in plotting a*tanh(x) with obviously wrong results

By defining in WinPlot a new function $ath(x)=\frac 1 2 ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ I eventually got right results.